# jQuery animate not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to set a background-color div property on DOM ready, then perform some animation, like this: `$("#test").css('background-color','red').animate({ 'background-color' : '#FFF'}, 500);`. Div looks like this `<div id="test">11</div>`, and it has a background-color property set in CSS file `#test{
    background-color:#FFF;
}`

Now the question - why animation is not working? You can see the code here - http://jsfiddle.net/hzdcM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have jQuery UI included to make you background-color animation to work

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/hzdcM/1/

Comment: jQuery UI may be a little overpowered for just animating colors :)

Answer (score 1):

Because jQuery cannot animate colors by itself, [search a jQuery plugin for that](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)

Answer (score 1):

`.animate()` function does not support animating colors. Use [jQuery color plugin.](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) or you can use jQuery UI Library.

UI Library is very heavy for just the color use.

Also you have use `backgroundColor` not `background-color` to animate the color properly.

```
$("#test")
   .css('backgroundColor','red')
   .animate({ 'backgroundColor' : '#FFF'}, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know of that lightweight solution. But now I'll need to use jQuery UI anyway, so I'll stick to that.